# how to do safe json parsing in swift?

Tags: json, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am getting a Json of images from sever i have created one modal class & under which i have declared images as member of that class.

```
class SomeClass: NSObject {

  var objImages:[Images] = [Images]()


}
```

**Images as class**

```
class Images {

  var thumbImage:String = ""
  var fullImage:String = ""

    init(dictionary:NSDictionary){

      fullImage = dictionary["thumb"] as? String ?? ""
      thumbImage = dictionary["full_url"] as? String ?? ""
  }
  init() {

  }

}
```

**Parsing the json data**

```
 if let arrImg  = dictionary["images"] {

      for value in arrImg as! NSArray {
        let tempImage:Images = Images(dictionary: value as! NSDictionary)
        recipeImages.append(tempImage)
      }
    }
```

below is the josn response

```
   { "images": [
      {
        "thumb": "https://mysevrer.com/v0/b/a.png”,
        "full_url": "https://mysevrer.com/v0/b/b.png"
      },
      {
        "thumb": "https://mysevrer.com/v0/b/a.png”",
        "full_url": "https://mysevrer.com/v0/b/b.png”"
      }
    ]
}
```

Please is it safe way to parse response ?

- What if i don'tget image as array
  What if i don't get the "thumb"
  & "full" as keys

Comment: If you are responsible for the server data you can control the safety. Make sure that always both key / value pairs are sent then you can forced unwrap the values. Use Swift `[String:String]` rather than type unspecified `NSDictionary` to get rid of the type casts

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but this will return an optional instance of Images. So it will return nil if the dictionary doesn't contain one or both of those keys.

```
class Images {

    var thumbImage:String

    var fullImage:String

    init?(dictionary:Dictionary<String,String>){

        guard let image = dictionary["thumb"] else { return nil }

        guard let thumb = dictionary["full_url"] else { return nil }

        self.fullImage = image

        self.thumbImage = thumb
    }
}
```

For the parsing part of the array.

```
guard let imagesArray = dictionary["images"] as? Array<Dictionary<String,String>> else { return }

for dict in imagesArray {

    guard let images = Images(dictionary: dict) else { continue }

    recipeImages.append(images)
}
```